# MutableLiveData contains same data after first call

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

I'm trying to learn MVVM by building an app using `MutableLiveData`, `RecyclerView.Adapter` and repositories.

The problem is, `MutableLiveData` contains same data after initialization. I mean, when comparing value of `MutableLiveData` with value that **isn't** set yet: they are already the same! I have a feeling that it sets value somewhere in background, and I don't know how to control it.

---

Initial data & `MutableLiveData` defined in my repository:

```kotlin
object ShopListRepositoryImpl: ShopListRepository {
    private val shopList = sortedSetOf(Comparator<ShopItem> {el1, el2 -> el1.id.compareTo(el2.id)})
    private val shopListLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<ShopItem>>()

    init {
        // init first items
        for (i in 1..5) {
            shopList.add(ShopItem("product $i", i*i, i % 2 == 0))
        }
        shopListLiveData.value = shopList.toList()
    }

    override fun addShopItem(shopItem: ShopItem) {
        shopList.add(shopItem)
        updateShopList()
    }

    override fun getShopList(): MutableLiveData<List<ShopItem>> { return shopListLiveData }

    ...

    private fun updateShopList() {
        shopListLiveData.value = shopList.toMutableList()
    }
}
```

The idea is to have only one `MutableLiveData` to work with.

Then, in my `ViewModel` I must have same `MutableLiveData`:

```kotlin
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val repository = ShopListRepositoryImpl
    // GetShopListUseCase contains only `execute`, that returns MutableLiveData from repo
    private val getShopListUseCase = GetShopListUseCase(repository)
    
    ...

    val shopList = getShopListUseCase.execute()
}
```

Before jumping to Activity, I'll show how data is updating using Adapter:

```kotlin
class MainActivityAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MainActivityAdapter.MainActivityViewHolder>() {
    var shopItemsList = mutableListOf<ShopItem>()
        set(value) {
            val diffUtilCallback = MainActivityDiffUtilCallback(shopItemsList, value)
            DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffUtilCallback).dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
            field = value
        }

    // overrides of `onCreateViewHolder`, `onBindViewHolder`, `getItemViewType` and `getItemCount`
}
```

In this Adapter all work done by `DiffUtil`, so, I won't call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

At last, `Activity`:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var adapter: MainActivityAdapter
    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        adapter = MainActivityAdapter()
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]

        adapter.shopItemOnClickListener = { viewModel.changeEnabledState(it) }
        adapter.shopItemOnLongClickListener = { viewModel.delete(it) }

        setContentView(binding.root)
        setupRecyclerView()

        viewModel.shopList.observe(this) { adapter.shopItemsList = it.toMutableList() }
    }

    fun setupRecyclerView() { 
        // set adapter, pool sizes, etc.
    }
}
```

---

UPD 1:

Code, which updates data for RecyclerView correctly:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    adapter = MainActivityAdapter()
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]

    adapter.shopItemOnClickListener = { viewModel.changeEnabledState(it) }
    adapter.shopItemOnLongClickListener = { viewModel.delete(it) }

    setContentView(binding.root)
    setupRecyclerView()

    binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
        val newList = adapter.shopItemsList.toMutableList()
        newList.add(ShopItem("Shopitem${newList.size}", 0, true))
        adapter.shopItemsList = newList
    }

//    viewModel.shopList.observe(this) {
//        adapter.shopItemsList = it.toMutableList()
//    }
}
```

I've just replaced `LiveData` observation with `FloatingActionButton` in my Activity, which adds new item per click. And, it works.

Comment: "when comparing value of MutableLiveData" Where and how are you doing this? It's not really clear what behavior you're describing. Maybe you could show the code that behaves differently than you expect so we can understand what the issue is.

Comment: @Tenfour04, thanks for response. I've added UPD 1 section with working code.

Comment: That's not really clarifying what the problem is that you're observing. You showed code that works as you expect. What is the code that *doesn't* work as you expect, and what were you expecting it to do? Is there any reason you aren't using ListAdapter? It's a much easier way to use DiffUtil than what you're doing, I think.

Comment: Code that doens't work written before UPD 1. It doesn't update data of RecyclerView, what is excepted. I've tried ListAdapter, but, problem remains the same: both ListAdapter and Adapter receives same data.

Comment: I use ListAdapter, so I'm not used to the way you're doing it, but I'm pretty sure you should move `field = value` before the `dispatchUpdatesTo` call, or else it will be looking at the old list while updating all the views. (ListAdpater is simpler because all you need to do is call `submitList`. No micro-managing like this.)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunate, no changes with moving `field = value` up. `ListAdapter` doesn't fixed the issue.